# Some issues about eigendecomposition and array signal processing

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, signal-processing

$a_n(r,\theta) = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{j}\hat{\Theta}n }, a(r,\theta) = [a_0(r,\theta),a_1(r,\theta),\dots,a_{N-1}(r,\theta)]^\mathrm{T}$,

where $\hat{\Theta}n =  {2\pi(n((2f_0d\sin\theta)/c)-m_n(2\Delta fr/c)) }$,  $\theta$ denotes the angle of the target, $r$ is the slant range of the target, $c$ is the speed of light, $m_n$ is random permutations from 0 to N-1, $n = 0,1,...,N-1$

$$A(r,\theta)=a(r,\theta)a(r,\theta)^\mathrm{H}$$

The N − 1 eigenvectors associated with the N − 1 zero eigenvalues of $A(r,\theta)$ span the noise subspace $G(r,\theta)$.

when $a(\hat{r},\hat{\theta})=a(r,\theta)$, where $\hat{r},\hat{\theta}$ denotes estimates of the range and angle of the target, respectively.

\begin{aligned}
&\boldsymbol{a}(\hat{r},\hat{\theta})^\mathrm{H}\boldsymbol{G}(r,\theta)\boldsymbol{G}(r,\theta)^\mathrm{H}\boldsymbol{a}(\hat{r},\hat{\theta}) \\
&=2(N-1)-2\cos[(\hat{\Theta}_1-\hat{\Theta}_0)-(\Theta_1-\Theta_0)] \\
&-2\cos[(\hat{\Theta}_2-\hat{\Theta}_0)-(\Theta_2-\Theta_0)]-\cdots  \\
&-2\cos[(\hat{\Theta}_{N-1}-\hat{\Theta}_0)-(\Theta_{N-1}-\Theta_0)]=0
\end{aligned}
How did it get this result? What is the detailed mathematical derivation.

Comment: What does $()^H$ mean? If $G(r, \theta)$ is a subspace, how is it appearing in your formula?

Comment: $()^H$  denotes the Hermitian transpose (also known as the conjugate transpose) of a matrix or a vector. $G(r,\theta)$ is the noise subspace. When The cross-spectral matrix $A(r,\theta)$ of the array output is decomposed, it yields eigenvalues and their corresponding eigenvectors. The eigenvectors corresponding to the larger eigenvalues constitute the signal subspace. On the other hand, the eigenvectors corresponding to the smaller eigenvalues form the noise subspace. the noise subspace and the signal subspace are orthogonal.

Comment: Therefore, the above results ($\boldsymbol{a}(\hat{r},\hat{\theta})^\mathrm{H}\boldsymbol{G}(r,\theta)\boldsymbol{G}(r,\theta)^\mathrm{H}\boldsymbol{a}(\hat{r},\hat{\theta})=0$) occurred. 
I don’t know how I derived this step $\begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{a}(\hat{r},\hat{\theta})^\mathrm{H}\boldsymbol{G}(r,\theta)\boldsymbol{G}(r,\theta)^\mathrm{H}\boldsymbol{a}(\hat{r},\hat{\theta}) =2(N-1)-2\cos[(\hat{\Theta}_1-\hat{\Theta}_0)-(\Theta_1-\Theta_0)]
\end{aligned}$.

Comment: Still confused. A subspace is a collection of vectors closed under scalar multiplication and addition. How is that appearing in a formula? Do you mean any vector from that subspace?

Comment: Sorry, my description may be inappropriate. $G(r,\theta)$ is actually composed of the eigenvectors corresponding to zero eigenvalues of $A(r,\theta)$. This means that it is an $ N-1\times N-1$ matrix.